# Trouble building first Mean stack app with Express - Nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

I am following a course on openclassroom to build my first full stack app with Express. Nodemon app crashed after I begin to optimize my app.js codes. Once I moved all my middle-wares into a separate file, Nodemon server continues to crash.....

**Here is my app.js code**

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const stuffRoutes = require('./routes/stuff');

// Cross Origin Resource Sharing
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

// Conection to MongoDB Atlas!
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-wns5r.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas!');
        console.error(error);
    });




 // Body Parser for structuring schematic data for our DB
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/stuff', stuffRoutes);




module.exports = app;
```

**Here is my middle wares in StuffRoutes - /routes/stuff**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();



const Thing = require('../models/thing');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const thing = new Thing({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
    price: req.body.price,
    userId: req.body.userId
  });
  thing.save().then(
    () => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post saved successfully!'
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  Thing.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  }).then(
    (thing) => {
      res.status(200).json(thing);
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(404).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});

router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const thing = new Thing({
    _id: req.params.id,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
    price: req.body.price,
    userId: req.body.userId
  });
  Thing.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, thing).then(
    () => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Thing updated successfully!'
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  Thing.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(
    () => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Deleted!'
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});

router.get('/' +
  '', (req, res, next) => {
  Thing.find().then(
    (things) => {
      res.status(200).json(things);
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});



module.exports = router;
```

**Error Message from command line when I start the server**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
C:\Users\Agabus\WEB_Project\DevC\EN_5614116_go-full-stack-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb\Go-full-stack-MEAN\backender\routes\stuff.js:1
��c


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Agabus\WEB_Project\DevC\EN_5614116_go-full-stack-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb\Go-full-stack-MEAN\backender\app.js:9:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Agabus\WEB_Project\DevC\EN_5614116_go-full-stack-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb\Go-full-stack-MEAN\backender\server.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: The error is indicating there is an unexpected token on line `\routes\stuff.js:1`
What is ��c?
There also appears to be an error in your `router.get`, what is `+''`

Comment: i removed the ```+ ' ' ``` from the ```router.get```, yet I still have the same Issue.
��c that is what the command line generates for me  ```C:\Users\Agabus\WEB_Project\DevC\EN_5614116_go-full-stack-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb\Go-full-stack-MEAN\backender\routes\stuff.js:1
��c```

Do you know how I can log that error to a ```.log``` or ```.txt``` file

Comment: The error is indicating the problem lies with `��c` so finding its cause is primary. Have you got any errors in your code? Are you using an add-on like eslint to check for syntax errors? Also try using the debug feature of your dev tool, sometimes you get more detail than the console.

Comment: And since you are using mongoose you can add, `mongoose.set('debug', true);` for some more details in the console. 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set

Comment: And further in your logs there is error indicated on `app.js:9:21)` and `server.js:2:13` start at the top from the first error indication, fix, rerun and work down the list. Errors will cascade and disappear once resolved.